# ControlActive ignores SetterBar

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

As shown in the following example, `ControlActive` does not seem to respond to controls such as `SetterBar`. Moving the slider resets the value of k, but changing the value of x via `SetterBar` does not.

Is there some other way to trigger an expensive calculation inside of a `Manipulate` when some discrete control variable is changed?

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{x, Spacer[10], y, Spacer[10], ControlActive[k = 0, k++]}]
 , {x, {5, 6, 7, 8}, ControlType -> SetterBar}
 , {y, 0, 1}
 , Initialization :> (k = 0)
 ]
```

Comment: I would consider `ControlActive` a switch and not a trigger. Therefore your question asks two different things, that aren't necessarily related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ControlActive` doesn't respond to `SetterBar`, as changing a value using `SetterBar` doesn't make [`$ControlActiveSetting`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ControlActiveSetting.html) being `True`.

Here is one way to make using the `SetterBar` reset `k`:

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{x, Spacer[10], y, Spacer[10], ControlActive[k = 0, k++], Spacer[10], 
  $ControlActiveSetting}], 
 {x, {5, 6, 7, 8}, ControlType -> SetterBar, TrackingFunction -> (x = #; k = 0; &)}, 
 {y, 0, 1}, Initialization :> (k = 0)]
```

Comment: Great! Am I correct that this can be used generally to trigger an expensive calculation, only when the value of the SetterBar is changed? That would be very useful.

Comment: @abwatson Yes, it should be.

Comment: @abwatson However, there are more ways to manage the evaluations inside a `Manipulate`. Some of them not suitable for your specific example, where `k=0` seems to represents the expansive calculation and `k++` the inexpensive one. The example in your question is more about how to set `k=0` after clicking on the `SetterBar`. Your `ControlActive` just keeps `k=0` as long as the `Manipulator` is used.

Comment: What are the other "ways to manage the evaluations inside a Manipulate?" I often have a need to perform an expensive calculation only when one of the control variables is changed.

Comment: @abwatson For example using `Refresh` or `Dynamic` with `TrackedSymbols` as a second argument. You can find many examples on this site and in the tutorials (e.g. [Advanced Manipulate Functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html)).